# Separation between Fine and Coarse location (definition)

Tags: architecture, software-design

To my understanding, COARSE permissions location are included in FINE location. Now my question is when do we need to separate these permissions, especially for users? Since they are somehow intertwined with one another.

Comment: Please add more details to this question because it's too broadly described in its current form

Comment: For example, if I want to create a simple prototype application that allows the user to find the nearest designated place or ordering food while simultaneously find the nearest drive-thru.